Convergence of Lipschitz constant $\big[h(T^n)\big]^{\frac{1}{n}}$
In this context, we will use the symbol $h(T)$ to denote the Lipschitz constant of a Lipschitz map $T$.
Let $X$ be a completed metric space and $T:\ X\longrightarrow X$ is a Lipschitz map. Then the consequence $a_n=\big[h(T^n)\big]^{\frac{1}{n}}$ is convergent.
I was given a brief instruction that let
$$ a=\inf_{n\in\mathbb N} a_n, $$
then for all $\epsilon>0$, there exist $m\in\mathbb N$ such that
\begin{align}
h(T^m)\leq (a+\epsilon)^m.\tag1
\end{align}
For any $n\in\mathbb N$, write $n=mq+r$, then
\begin{align}
a&\leq a_n=\big[h(T^{mq+r})\big]^{\frac{1}{n}}
\newline &\leq h(T^r)^{\frac{1}{n}}(a+\epsilon)^{\frac{mq}{n} }.\tag2
\end{align}
For some large $N$, we deduce that for any $n\geq N$.
$$a\leq a_n\leq a+2\epsilon. $$
This show that the consequence $a_n$ is convergent to $a$.
However, there're two points of the sketch that I still yet to understand clearly, which I labeled (1) and (2). I really hope someone would help me to explain it more explicitly. Thanks.

If $a = \inf_n a_n$, then any number larger than $a$ is not a lower bound of the sequence $\{a_n\}$. In particular $a + \epsilon$ is not a lower bound for any $\epsilon > 0$. This means that $a + \epsilon$ must exceed some term of the sequence.
In your case, since $a = \inf_n h(T^n)^{1/n}$, there must be some $m$ satisfying $h(T^m)^{1/m} < a+ \epsilon$. This works out to $h(T^m) < (a + \epsilon)^m$.
Next observe that for $p,q \in \mathbf N$ you have $$d(T^{p+q}(x), T^{p+q}(y)) = d(T^p(T^q(x)), T^p(T^q(y))) \le h(T^p)d(T^q(x), T^q(y)) \le h(T^p)h(T^q)d(x,y)$$ so that $h(T^{p+q}) \le h(T^p)h(T^q)$. By induction it follows that $h(T^{pq}) \le h(T^p)^q$. Combine this observation with (1) to obtain
$$h(T^{mq+r}) \le h(T^{mq}) h(T^r) \le h(T^m)^q h(T^r) \le (a+\epsilon)^{mq} h(T^r).$$

Thank you so much, your answer was really clear and coherent.
